# React Native 'run-android' mac issue

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native project that successfully runs on iOS emulator however, when running `react-native run-android` I get the following error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

I have downloaded Android studio, setup a virtual device, installed necessary JDK.

How can I resolve?

Full error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
          - generalDebugRuntimeElements
          - mlkitDebugRuntimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'generalDebugRuntimeElements' capability VerizonApp:react-native-camera:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'generalDebug' but wasn't required.
                  - Found react-native-camera 'general' but wasn't required.
              - Compatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Variant 'mlkitDebugRuntimeElements' capability VerizonApp:react-native-camera:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'mlkitDebug' but wasn't required.
                  - Found react-native-camera 'mlkit' but wasn't required.
              - Compatible attributes:
                  - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
                  - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' <-- insert this line
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to set the variant in your `android/app/build.gradle`.

Read here for more details (Point number 4) : https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/installation